# regular expression for specific URL

Tags: java, expression

How could i use a regular-expression in java to extract URLs in the form

```
/p/{any set of characters}/bugs/{any set of numbers start from 0 to 999}
```

From text file. I tried one as the following

```
final String regex = "(\\/p\\/.*\\/bugs\\/(\\d{0,3}))";
```

But i didn't work fine for me.

Comment: Sample data would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you have those backslashes in your regex.  Additionally, use a negated character class to match *any set of characters* in the pattern.  The following might work for you:

```
/p/[^/]*/bugs/[0-9]{1,3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
final String regex = "/p/.+/bugs/[0-9]{1,3}";
```